# Download file from POST request

Tags: python, django, post

I would like to download a file when user submits a button. It's a `POST request`. I don't overcome to return the `HttpResponse` in my code.

This is my view :

```
class ExportDownloadView(View):
    """ Create name authentification to download export file with expiration time """
    template_name = 'export_download.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        export_name = kwargs.pop('name', None)
        ExportFile.objects.get(name__iexact=export_name)

        if 'resp' in request.POST:
            resp = self.downloadFile(export_name)
            return resp

        context = {
            'name': export_name
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def downloadFile(self, export_name):

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = export_name
        if fs.exists(filename):
            with fs.open(filename) as xls:
                response = HttpResponse(xls, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + export_name
                return response
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound(_('The requested xls file was not found in our server.'))
```

And this is the HTML file :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Export File : {{ name }}" name="resp" />
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-default">{% trans 'Back' %}</a>    
</form>
```

When user clicks on submit button, he should be able to download the linked file. But, I don't know why the `if 'resp' in request.POST` is never called.

I miss something ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why should it be? It's in the `get` method, which is not called on POST, unsurprisingly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right ... It's a mistake from me .. I apologize .

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @DanielRoseman, it's a mistake from me. I called `POST request` in `get()` method ! Obviously it doesn't work !

In my view :

```
if 'resp' in request.GET:
    resp = self.downloadFile(export_name)
    return resp
```

In my HTML template :

```
<form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Export File : {{ name }}" name="resp" />
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-default">{% trans 'Back' %}</a>
</form>
```

It works like a charm !